# sequencer.startRecording() not starting right away? Java MIDI

Tags: java, audio, input, midi, audio-player

So I am obtaining midi data from my keyboard and I start recording using

```
sequence = new Sequence(Sequence.PPQ, 24);
currentTrack = sequence.createTrack();
sequencer.setSequence(sequence);
sequencer.setTickPosition(0);
sequencer.recordEnable(currentTrack, -1);
sequencer.startRecording();
```

and I use a button to stop recording it and save it to a file. When I play back the  midi file it takes about 4 seconds to start what was recorded. I even play the midifiles that it saves on an external program and it seems like it adds about 4 seconds of nothing at the beginning of the recording. Does anyone know why this is or how to fix it so that when I play back the midifile, it starts right away?

Comment: I dont know this since I havent used recording - but can you post a midi file?

Comment: @gpasch https://ufile.io/3s27j

Comment: ok i see what you mean probably some byte causes the player to take that as pause or something - I can convert this to a file without delays - I'm gonna try to see if it works ok since it;s 'experimental' - but this is not gonna address the main issue - maybe someone will answer it

Comment: I see the saving inserts a byte 171 which is this delay - I assume you use the normal MidiSystem.write() It's probably something wrong there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is this function that takes the file and removes the first note (event). In this case the system added an event with code 144, which is for Note_On, in place of some control command at the beginning of the file (the code 171 which is set as the duration of this first note tells me that that was meant). So we remove the first event.

You can apply this after saving.

```
  public void write(Sequence s) {
    int i=0, j;
    int max=0;
    Vector notes=new Vector();
    try {
      Sequence s2=MidiPlayer.createSequence();
      Track tr2=s2.createTrack();
      long tlen=s.getMicrosecondLength()/s.getTickLength();
      Track[] tr=s.getTracks();
//      System.out.println("has tracks "+tr.length);
      Vector note=new Vector();
      for(i=0; i<tr.length; i++) {
        int l=tr[i].size()-1;
//      System.out.println(i+" has events "+l);
        int sum=0, start=0;
        MidiEvent mi=null;
        ShortMessage sm=null;
        byte[] dat=null;
        int tick=0, tick2=0;
        for(j=0; j<l; j++) {
          mi=tr[i].get(j);
          if(mi.getMessage().getStatus()==MetaMessage.META) { System.out.println("meta "); continue; }
          sm=(ShortMessage)mi.getMessage();
//      System.out.println("sm "+sm.getCommand()+" "+sm.getStatus()+" "+sm.getData1()+" "+sm.getData2());
          dat=sm.getMessage();
//        for(int ik=0; ik<dat.length; ik++) System.out.print(dat[ik]+" ");
//        System.out.println();
          tick2=(int)mi.getTick();
          int key=sm.getData1(), vel=sm.getData2();
        System.out.println(j+" "+(tick2-tick)+" "+tlen+" "+tick2+" "+tick+" ch "+sm.getChannel()+" "+key);
          if(j==0) { tick=tick2; continue; }
          notes.add(new int[]{key, vel, max, tick2-tick});
          max+=tick2-tick;
          tick=tick2;
          }
        }
        for(i=0; i<notes.size(); i++) {
          int[] ii=(int[])notes.get(i);
          if(ii==null) break;
          ShortMessage on = new ShortMessage();
          on.setMessage(ShortMessage.NOTE_ON, 0, ii[0], ii[1]);
          ShortMessage off = new ShortMessage();
          off.setMessage(ShortMessage.NOTE_OFF, 0, ii[0], ii[1]);
          tr2.add(new MidiEvent(on, ii[2]));
          tr2.add(new MidiEvent(off, ii[2]+ii[3]));
        }   
        String t=""+(System.currentTimeMillis()/1000);
        MidiPlayer.write(s2, "new-"+t+".mid");
    }
    catch(Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
  }
```

Comment: This worked, thanks! Do you have any idea why it would add this at the beginning of the file? Is this how sequencer.startRecording() usually works?

Comment: I think it has to do with hardware - how your keyboard (or a keyboard)  is connected etc - I havent done that - plus the implementation of MidiSystem.wite(): it is an abstract class that is used there and I dont know where the implementation is / that seems faulty - maybe we'll find it some day